# Drivers for LG 32LK 330 UB TV?

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-mate, tv, lg

I  got a LG Tv model 32LK330 UB.

Monitor Preferences is showing it as a Goldstar 52 inch HDMI-0.

The picture quality is not as good as it should be.

Do I need a driver for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need a driver for it?

No. You need a driver for the HDMI port. That is not one where you can switch drivers (same as with USB and VGA).

Settings on the TV to consider:

- Resolution of the TV is 1366x768. That is about only 51% of the 1920x1080 resolution.
- Formats supported: 480i, 480p, 720p, 1080i, 1080p_60, 1080p_24, 1080p_30. The numbers behind the 1080 are the frames per second. 1080i or 1080p_60 is going to be the best quality.

Comment: So set resolution to 1366x768 for best clarity? @Rindwind